# How to get average of 16bit ADC readings?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, adc, mathematics

I have an [Adafruit ADS1115 analog-to-digital converter](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/arduino-code), configured in single ended mode. I want to average over 3 sensor readings to increase the reading stability.

```
  //initialize variables
  int16_t rawData, ambient;
  int i=0;

  // start loop
  while(i<3) {
      rawData = ads.readADC_SingleEnded(0); //read from ADC
      // divide sensor reading by three
      // (doing so after summation will lead to an overflow)
      rawData=rawData/3;                    
      Serial.println(rawData); // print data to serial for debugging (OK)
      ambient+=rawData;
      i+=1;
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("I LIVVVVEEE"); // print text to serial for debugging (OK)
  }

  // Print signal (NOT OK)
  Serial.print("Ambient is ");
  Serial.println(ambient);
```

The "rawData" is printed correctly on the serial monitor. However, the value for "ambient" can be crazy: the resulting output is over an order of magnitude higher. Somehow, the summation doesn't seem to be performed correctly.

Comment: this is not avarege of 3 readings. it is a sum a of 1/3 of readings

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to average out three sensor ADC reading first you need to store and add them all then divide it by 3.

```
 int16_t rawData =0;
 int32_t avg=0,ambient=0;
  int i=0;


 while(i<3) {
      rawData = ads.readADC_SingleEnded(0); //read from ADC
      // divide sensor reading by three
      // (doing so after summation will lead to an overflow)
     Serial.println(rawData); // print data to serial for debugging (OK)
     avg += rawData;
      i++;
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("I LIVVVVEEE"); // print text to serial for debugging (OK)
  }
  abmient = avg /3;
  avg = 0;
  // Print signal (NOT OK)
  Serial.print("Ambient is ");
  Serial.println(ambient);
```

Comment: This approach is great for small numbers. However, the ADC is 16 bit. By adding three 16bit values, this may (can) lead to buffer overflow for "ambient".

Comment: @plasma, sum of 3 16 bit numbers will not run out of 32 bit

Comment: @Juraj there is nothing like that. I just made changes in his program.

Comment: appreciated....

Comment: you will actually get more stable readings if you take the _median_ of the 3 readings instead of the _mean_. consider reading `12,13,5` when the true reading is 13. with avg you get `10` (err=3), but with median you get `12` (err=1). I used this method for a DMM project and it made a HUGE difference compared to my naive oversample+avg method... You can also adjust how many internal AD1115 samples are collected, and at the expense of reading time, get a more stable set of values from the get go.

Comment: @dandavis Its not necessary that always median will be the right value. It might happen in your case but I had tested it on ST controller where I take average of 4 readings and I get the expected value, though I calculated voltage using ADC, the error I got is about -0.01V from actual voltage.

Comment: Calculating a mean the way the OP does is absolutely valid. It doesn't make a difference wether the sum or the summands are divided by the number of values. Your code might fix the issue, but that's because you initialize the variables explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize `ambient` to zero, so it got whatever happened to be in that place of memory when it got instantiated. Some unpredictable, seemingly random data.

Comment: are you saying that `int16_t ambient; Serial.println(ambient, DEC);` could show something besides `0`?

Comment: @dandavis: Yes, absolutely. The value of `ambient` here is indeterminate. In some circumstances, using such a value can even lead to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior).